# How to use service class in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new in both `angular2` and `.net core` I followed [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103) tutorial and learned pretty solution to work with angular (*and .netcore*). I just have a problem!

When I create a service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/RX'
import { AccountSummary } from './account-summary.type'
import { AccountDetail } from './account-detail.type'
import { AccountType } from './account-type.enum'

@Injectable()

export class AccountService
{
    constructor(private http : Http)
    {
     }
getAccountSummeries()
{
    debugger
    return this.http.get('api/Bank/GetAccountSummeries')
        .map(response => response.json() as AccountSummary[])
        .toPromise();
}
}
```

and import it in `app.module.share.ts` file:

```
   .
   .

import { AccountService } from './components/shared/account.service' //Here<<


export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],

    //Namespace Off Components:
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AccountlistComponent,
        AccountSummaryComponent,
        ExampleComponent,
        FormatAccountNumberPipe,

        HeaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
         //paths...
        ])
    ],
    providers: [AccountService] //Here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

};
```

iv got this error when i ran the application:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AccountService!
>   Error: No provider for AccountService!
>   at Error (native)

I use my service like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountSummary } from '../../shared/account-summary.type'
import { AccountType } from '../../shared/account-type.enum'
import { AccountService } from '../../shared/account.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'account-list',
    templateUrl: './account-list.component.html'
})
export class AccountlistComponent {

    cashAccounts: AccountSummary[];
    creditAccounts: AccountSummary[];
    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { 
    }

    ngOninit() {
        this.accountService.getAccountSummeries().then(accounts => { 
        this.cashAccounts = accounts })
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also show you app.module file.

Comment: @MattSugden i actually made confuse ...my proj is angular SPA template with .net core and i have 3 app.module named:{app.module.client , app.module.server,app.module.shared}...the problem solved when i add this provide in app.module.server!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exception, you didn't add in module. Add `AccountService` in your app.module.ts file

```
providers: [AccountService]
```

Comment: thanks ....i actually made confuse ...my proj is angular SPA template with .net core and i have 3 app.module named:{app.module.client , app.module.server,app.module.shared}...the problem  solved when i add this provide in app.module.server!!!!!